# How hide snackbar when NavigationView open?

Tags: android, android-navigationview, android-snackbar

How hide `NavigationView` when `shackbar` show?

So that `snackbar` doesn't overlap `NavigationView`

Comment: Use `drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen()` method to check if the drawer is open and then do `drawerLayout.closeDrawer()` on `snackbar.show()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Snackbar Callbacks`

```
snackbar.addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
      //see Snackbar.Callback docs for event details
      ...  
    }

    @Override
    public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
       drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

## try this

- Here there are `two` way to `close your drawer`

  1. `close` drawer with `animation` like this

---

```
snackbar.addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {

@Override
public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
  //see Snackbar.Callback docs for event details
  ...  
}

@Override
public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
   drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
});
```

---

2. `close` drawer without `animation` like this

---

```
snackbar.addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {

@Override
public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
  //see Snackbar.Callback docs for event details
  ...  
}

@Override
public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
   drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START,false);
}
});
```